# If a question involves presuppositions with which we disagree, are expressions of said disagreement appropriate as answers?

Tags: discussion

Suppose you were on the PhysicsSE and asked a question about string theory, such as, "Why does string theory involve 10<sup>500</sup>+ 'parallel universes'/'landscapes'/'vacua'?" Perhaps, in specifying the question, you acknowledge either (A) that there are background objections to string theory as a research program or (B) particular objections to the samples of string theory leading to the how-many-vacua problem. Perhaps not. At any rate, if someone posts an answer (or even a comment) going off on a tangent about how string theory is bad/misguided/w/e, and that's where their response more or less halts, is that person offering an appropriate comment/answer?

Slightly similar issue: what about responses like, "I don't understand string theory, and neither does anyone else, really, so you're wasting your time asking about it"? Well, maybe some people *do* understand string theory. Maybe issues with understanding/"making sense" are really just reading comprehension issues, and if someone took the time to charitably interpret the material they're reading, they'd understand it. They might not know the answer to the question just by comprehending the question, and perhaps some philosophical questions (to switch to the matter at hand) are such that understanding the question *would* mean knowing the answer in turn. I am not going to claim to understand/know, perfectly, what understanding/knowledge themselves are, however. Anyway, if in the opening question, the poster specifically waived certain definitional issues, or settled them by means of, "For the purposes of this argument..." would the poster have delimited the range of appropriate responses to those cohering with the definitions presented? It would seem dialectically unfair to expect every question on the PhilosophySE to go into details about every objection that could be raised to whichever presuppositions. Like, if someone asks a question about Kripke's modal semantics, one might, in principle, dispute aspects of Kripke's preceding gloss of modality on the one hand, and semantics on the other. And then one dispute the more generic propositional logic and philosophy of language on offer, etc. However, voicing all such objections would seem to derail the point of asking focused questions on this site, and criticizing the original poster's question on such grounds would also seem to violate, then, PhilosophySE protocol (or rather SE protocol in general).